# find the text inside out side the target element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the text in the dropped place

```
this.on("drop", function (event) {
    console.log("event", event)
    var imageUrl = event.dataTransfer.getData('URL');
    console.log(imageUrl)
    console.log($(event.target))
    console.log($(event.target).closest('span'))
    //console.log($(event.target).parent().getElementById('displayName'),"by id")
    console.log($(event.target).parent().getElementsByTagName('span'), "by tag")
});
```

The html is like

```
<div class="main-div">
<form class="form"><img src=""/></form>
<div><span>required text</span></div>
<div>
```

when I do `console.log($(event.target))` some time I am getting the 
form elemnt, some times I am getting the image tag. then how can I find the text which I mentioned as required text?

Comment: `$(event.target).next('div').find('span').text()`

Comment: I have a small change in the question

Comment: sometimes I will get the innermost element as target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you `event.target` refers to `FORM`/`IMG` element. Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `form`, then use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling `DIV` then [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get `SPAN` element

```
$(event.target).closest('form').next('div').find('span').text()
```

Comment: if I get form as target, will it cause problem? selected elemnt itself is form, then closest form?

Comment: @vishnuprasadkv, No it won't be an issue, as `.closest()` starts traversal from itself